# htaccess redirects adds question mark to url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following in my htaccess:

```
#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?/$1 [L]

#No WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^myrealdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myrealdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#Always redirect to SSL pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I want the `www` to be redirected and I want all pages to be `https`. It seems to work, but when I try to go to `https://www.d.com/hello` it redirects to `https://d.com/?/hello`.

Where did that extra question mark come from?

In addition, creating a [facebook like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) seems to not like my domain at all. The button appears blank and I think its do with the above...?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: From the rules that have a question mark perhaps?

Comment: Is `/hello` an existing file or folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally a poorly understood part of mod_rewrite.  All rules (unless a rule is followed by `[L]`) are processed in order and the rules *change the value of the URI*.  They do not change the value of `%{THE_REQUEST}`.

Hence your second rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?/$1 [L]
```

Causes a request for `/hello` to be rewritten to `?/hello`.  The input to the next rule is now `?/hello`.

The next rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myrealdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Uses `$1` to match the entire URI and sends a 301 redirect to that URI on a new domain.  That's where the question mark comes from.  It's an internal rewrite followed by a redirect in the same request.

You can solve this problem by moving the `^application` rewrite and the valid file rewrite to the bottom, after all the redirect rules.

Your https redirect is missing `[L,R=301]`.

I have no idea about Facebook like buttons but after fixing the question mark problem, if it still doesn't work, try asking again or reading though the Facebook documentation.